# how do I implement "Choose Existing Photo" in my app like in default iphone phonebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, capture

I want to develop an app which has functionality same as iphone phonebook capturing image and choosing iamge,

what should I to use for doing such

I have made an UIImageView and a button for UIActionSheet,

now I want to perform "Take Photo" and "Choose Existing Photo" options in my app

help me out, I do appreciate

thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey @Veer you need to use UIImagePickerController

check out the documentation
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html
and check out this link

**http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/**

It has sample examples about the same.

Edit you can use these methods to get the image in you UIImageView object

```
- (void)selectPhotos
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    imageView.image = image;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @Robin, I know this but it is not working with me, having confusion, can U guide me a bit more ?

Comment: and I am using UIActionSheet, so hope your code will be according to it

Comment: @Robin, This is not working,                                                                                                                            picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
   //picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

Comment: Nothing is happening, I can't go any control, just it came back as I click any button on UIActionSheet.

Comment: It is calling method, but nothing is happening, means it is not transfering control,

Comment: did you implement the delegate method for the same `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Comment: ya, I have Implemented, as below  @interface Settings : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

Comment: what is the sourcetype for picker that you have used.

Comment: @Robin, I am calling your selectPhotos method in my ViewDidLoad as [self selectPhotos], it is calling method, but nothing happening onwards....

Comment: you can use the code from this link https://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test to implement the image picker.

Comment: hey Robin, I am using simulator, do you think it will work here or not? because everything is correct else,,,

Comment: yes i have used it in many of my apps and it works fine can you try clean build and delete the build directory from the project folder.